# @RestController cannot convert from ResponseEntity<Void>

Tags: spring, spring-restcontroller

I've got following code for my REST Controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "foo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Result> doSomething(@RequestParam int someParam)
{
    try
    {
        final Result result = service.getByParam(someParam);
        if (result == null)
        {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        } else
        {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(result);
        }

    } catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LOG.error("Error blah", ex);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

I would like to use *ResponseEntity.noContent().build()* but Eclipse gives me:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from ResponseEntity to
>   ResponseEntity

Is there any way to overcome this?

Update:

It is possible to create helper like this:

```
public class ResponseUtils
{
    public static <T> ResponseEntity<T> noContent()
    {
        return withStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }

    public static <T> ResponseEntity<T> internalServerError()
    {
        return withStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

    public static <T> ResponseEntity<T> accepted()
    {
        return withStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    }

    private static <T> ResponseEntity<T> withStatus(HttpStatus status)
    {
        return new ResponseEntity<T>(status);
    }
}
```

So I can use it like:

```
return ResponseUtils.noContent();
```

But maybe there is built-in functionality for this stuff?

Comment: What is throwing the error exactly? Which line?

Comment: Make sure the imported package of the ResponseEntity is the correct one.

Comment: `return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();` is not working and there is error I've mentioned

If I use `new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)` then there is no error

Answer (score 1):

Is this that you want to achieve?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "foo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<Result> doSomething(@RequestParam int someParam) {
    try {
        final Result result = service.getByParam(someParam);
        if (result == null) {
            return ResponseUtils.noContent();
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<Result>(result, null, HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
        }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return ResponseUtils.internalServerError();
        }
}

//you forgot to add static keyword in this Utils class
public static class ResponseUtils{
    public static <T> ResponseEntity<T> noContent(){
       return withStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }

    public static <T> ResponseEntity<T> internalServerError(){
       return withStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }

    public static <T> ResponseEntity<T> accepted(){
       return withStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    }

    private static <T> ResponseEntity<T> withStatus(HttpStatus status){
       return new ResponseEntity<T>(status);
    }
}
```

Check imports, I am using:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
```

Comment: Thanks. This copy-paste from my helper class but I'm looking for built-in functionality (if it exists)